# Loop through cells and change font

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, size

I'm trying to loop through all cells in a row and change the font size using the following criteria:

- If the font size is less than 10, then change the font size to 10

This works if all cells in the worksheet are the same font size. It returns `null` if any of the cells in the sheet have a different font size. If I have a font size of 8 in A1 and a size of 20 in A2, there is no change.

```
Sub SetSheetFont(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim NumRows As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Range("A1").Select
    With ws
        ' If the font size is lower than 10, set to 10
        For x = 1 To NumRows
            If .Cells.Font.Size < 10 Then .Cells.Font.Size = 10
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

The end goal is to loop through all cells in the column until there is a certain number of empty cells, then start on the next column (in this case B1).

How might I at least accomplish this in one column? I'm pretty sure I can get it working if I start there.

Comment: Maybe this could be a nice usecase for `FindFormat` and `ReplaceFormat`. Not sure though.

Comment: Also your loop doesn't really change each iteration.  You're checking the same cells each time (the *entire sheet's cells*).  If you intend to check the cells in column A, change `.Cells.` to `.Cells(x,1).`  Then it'll loop through all the cells from row 1 to `numRows`, checking the cell in Column A.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through all the cells in the `UsedRange`

```
Sub SetSheetFont(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim myCell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        For each myCell in ws.UsedRange
            ' If the font size is lower than 10, set to 10
            If myCell.Font.Size < 10 Then myCell.Font.Size = 10
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Side note: in general, you want to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment, I think this could be a good usecase for `FindFormat` and `ReplaceFormat`:

```
Dim x As Double

'Set ReplaceFormat just once
Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
Application.ReplaceFormat.Font.Size = 10

'Set FindFormat in a For loop
For x = 1 To 9.5 Step 0.5
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    Application.FindFormat.Font.Size = x
    ws.Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
Next x
```

This prevents iteration over all `ws.Cells`. The loop is necessary because we cant set something like: `Application.FindFormat.Font.Size < 10`. And because `Font.Size` will auto-adjust (at least for me) to the nearest 0.5 (and 1 being the smallest size) we can step from 1 to 9.5 with a step of 0.5.

And as per your description, you might want to change it up to `ws.UsedRange` as per @cybernetic.nomad mentioned. So it would read: `ws.UsedRange.Replace...`

Comment: And as an additional option, OP can use `ws.Range("A1:C1000").Replace ...`.  I always hesitate personally to use `UsedRange`, as it may not necessarily get what you expect the Used Range to be.  And `.Cells.`, of course, does it over all cells. Just wanted to show the option of using a specific range also. :)

Answer (score 2):

Keeping your code, as commented, you would want to access each cell (not all cells, which is what `.Cells.` does:

```
For x = 1 To NumRows
    If .Cells(x,1).Font.Size < 10 Then .Cells(x,1).Font.Size = 10
Next
```

This will loop through column A. (the `1` in `.Cells(x,1)`).

I would also suggest using `.End(xlUp)` instead of `xlDown`, in the event your column A has a blank row separating Data.  If that's okay, then you can keep it...the other option is: `NumRows = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row` (Also, use `Long` for `x`:

```
Sub SetSheetFont(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim x As Long, NumRows as Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        NumRows = .Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        ' If the font size is lower than 10, set to 10
        For x = 1 To NumRows
            If .Cells(x,1).Font.Size < 10 Then .Cells(x,1).Font.Size = 10
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Edit: To be sure, `xlDown` will work, just note it'll stop at the first Empty cell.  Using `xlUp` as I did, will be sure to get *all* rows in Column A...which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: `xlDown` might have been on purpose though, since OP mentioned *"loop through all cells in the column until there's a certain number of empty cells"*. A little unclear from OP's end I guess. Even so, a solid answer :)

Comment: @JvdV - Agreed on `xlDown`, I tried to note that in my Answer but I'll edit to clarify.